# Making Merge in MariaDB (Update when matched , insert when not matched)

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to make a merge for **MariaDB** DB.
I need to insert values if no ASIN exists in the table, or to Update values if it exists.

```
MERGE INTO asin_list al USING ( SELECT asin FROM asin_list WHERE asin = 'B006UCNI38' ) alexist ON ( al.asin = alexist.asin ) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
    SET al.updated_at = '2022-03-13 12:11:21', al.price=19.85, al.product_quantity=10
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ( asin, price, seller, shipping_cost, dispatch_time, product_type, product_quantity, aditional_scraped, created_at, updated_at, seller_name, brand, scraped_at )
VALUES
    ( 'B006UCNI38', 7.49, 'SBA', 0, '', 'PRIME', 30, 1, '2022-03-13 12:11:21', '2022-03-13 12:11:21', 'Amazon', 'WD-40', '2022-03-13 12:11:21' );
```

But I get an erro saying:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version
```

Can you help me on how can I achive this?
Have in mind that if i make the same query in mySql it works, Issue is only with MaridDb.

Comment: [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert/#insert-on-duplicate-key-update) and `asin` needs to be a primary or unique key if it isn't already.

Comment: Or if these are all the fields of the table [REPLACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replace/).

Comment: @danblack `REPLACE` will effectively execute a `DELETE` and `INSERT` which may have performance and other repercussions.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, MariaDB does not support the `MERGE` DML statement, which was added in the [SQL 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003) standard revision.

MariaDB only supports these [data insert/load statements](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inserting-loading-data/) and these [data update/delete](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/changing-deleting-data/) statements.

Your best bet is to use, as @danblack suggests, [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/) which is a MySQL/MariaDB-specific syntax which achieves the same result.